# (Seemingly) identical strings converted to uppercase differently

Tags: string, perl, uppercase

I'm encountering a very strange problem with the conversion to uppercase of two "identical" strings. The program is reading lines from a website and compares it with lines stored in a textfile. If the line is not found, it adds it to the end of the file. This works perfectly unless the line contains special characters. For some reason, the comparison results in a non-match. I compare the two strings by converting them to uppercase first and that is where it goes wrong. Below is some code. I've omitted the part where the two variables are filled. I'm just showing the weird part.

```
print "$pageLine <-> $dbLine\n";
print uc( $pageLine ) . " <-> " . uc( $dbLine ) . "\n";
```

This results in

```
Diëtisten <-> Diëtisten
DIëTISTEN <-> DIËTISTEN
```

Notice that ë in the first is not converted to uppercase.

```
foreach my $kar (split( //, $pageLine) ) {
  print ord($kar) . ":";
}
print "\n";
foreach my $kar (split( //, $dbLine) ) {
  print ord($kar) . ":";
}
print "\n";
```

This results in:

```
68:105:235:116:105:115:116:101:110:32:40:78:86:68:41:
68:105:235:116:105:115:116:101:110:32:40:78:86:68:41:
```

Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html might be a good read, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minimal demonstration:

```
my $s = "\xEB";
utf8::downgrade( my $d = $s );
utf8::upgrade(   my $u = $s );
printf "%vX %vX %s\n", $d, $u, $d eq $u ? "same" : "different";
$_ = uc($_) for $d, $u;
printf "%vX %vX %s\n", $d, $u, $d eq $u ? "same" : "different";
```

Output:

```
EB EB same
EB CB different
```

---

By default, for backwards-compatibility, `uc` will only uppercase ASCII characters if the input scalar's `UTF8` flag is off. It's an instance of The Unicode Bug<sup>[1]</sup> that's fixed by adding the following:

```
use feature qw( unicode_strings );
```

The above can be done indirectly by adding the following:

```
use 5.012;
```

References: [`unicode_strings`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature#The_'unicode_strings'_feature), [`feature`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature), [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

---

1. When the behaviour of code depends on the storage format of a string, that code is said to suffer from The Unicode Bug.

Comment: That indeed solved the problem. :)
Is it save to replace "use strict;" with "use 5.012;" in all my modules?

Comment: Yes. "*Similarly, if the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.12.0, strictures are enabled lexically as with use strict*"